# Stop Dictionary Pop-Up Window

Tags: applescript, dictionary

< 3.5 GHz, 6-Core Mac Pro (2013 MacPro6,1) with 16GB RAM and D700 GPUs, running macOS 10.14.6 >

Greetings, folks!

After reinstalling MacOS 10.14.6, whenever I type cmd-control-d, a window pops up with dictionary entries.

I have never seen this before (since 1986!) and have been unable to find where the command is controlled so that I can stop the pop-up window from appearing. I need this to stop, as I have used cmd-control-d for decades to generate a time-and-date stamp.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Comment: If you select a word and press that key combo macOS will define the selected word. Do you mean that or is there some other behavior. You can view these in System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Services. Dictionary pop-up is not defined on my Mac (same macOS) maybe yours is?

Comment: What OS version were you running before? It's been in the OS for years. Have you tried overriding the key in System Prefs to do something else?

Answer (score 1):

According to Apple documentation [Mac keyboard shortcuts](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236#text)  ⌃+⌘+D is built-in document shortcut:

> **Document shortcuts**
>
> The behavior of these shortcuts may vary with the
> app you're using.
>
> /.../
>
> Control-Command-D: Show or hide the definition of the selected word.

This shortcut is enabled irrespective whether `System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Services > Searching > Look up in Dictionary` assigned or not.

Keyboard shortcut for 'Look up in Dictionary' will open Dictionary app and not pop up window, so these are different things.

On my machine I observed 'varying behavior' as stated in documentation: I have not assigned shortcut but this key combination opens dictionary pop-up in Mail and Notes but not in Safari. Probably because MacOS doesn't consider webpage as 'document'.

Comment: So, is there a way to re-assign it or to get rid of it through terminal? I need this shortcut for some other purpose.